# List with dictionaries - count values for all keys (Python)

Tags: python

Considering there's a list with multiple dictionaries, sharing the same keys.

```
data = [{'count': 3, 'os': 'Windows'},
        {'count': 2, 'os': 'Windows'},
        {'count': 5, 'os': 'Linux'},
        {'count': 1, 'os': 'Linux'}]
```

How to sum up their values? Expected:

```
data = [{'count': 5, 'os': 'Windows'},{'count': 6, 'os': 'Linux'}]
```

Comment: Is the data always in the same format? If so, you may want to consider saving it in tuple-form: ``data = [('Windows', 3), ('Linux', 2), .. ]``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import itertools

data = [
    {'count': 3, 'os': 'Windows'},
    {'count': 2, 'os': 'Windows'},
    {'count': 5, 'os': 'Linux'},
    {'count': 1, 'os': 'Linux'}
]

results = []
for key, val in itertools.groupby(data, lambda v: v['os']):
    count = sum(item['count'] for item in val)
    results.append({'count' : count, 'os' : key})

>>> results
>>> [{'count': 5, 'os': 'Windows'}, {'count': 6, 'os': 'Linux'}]
```

Comment: Simple and straight-forward! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Itertools has some very magnificent functions and classes.

Comment: Totally agree. All praise `yield`!

Comment: A little addition. Turned out it needs sorting on larger inputs.

Before:
`for key,val in itertools.groupby(data, lambda v: v['os'])`

After:
`for key,val in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['os']), lambda v: v['os'])`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

sum_dict = defaultdict(int)

for d in dicts: # your dictionaries
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        sum_dict[key] += value
```

For sure you can compress it into as single working, but less readable one-liner. Also, class [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) might be useful here. [collections](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections) and [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools) contain plenty of *very* useful stuff.

Comment: Haha, true. Though, if OP ever considers changing the format of his data, it may be useful.